# How do I append to a hyperlink using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am looking to add `"&location=/xyz/123"` to the end of every hyperlink on a page.

How do I go about doing this? I am somewhat new to jQuery

I am thinking something like this but I am not 100%

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('a').attr('href').append("&location=/xyz/123");
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, attr) {
        return attr + "&location=/xyz/123";
   });
});
</script>`

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attr` function, when used as an accessor, returns a string. There's no `append` function on strings. You probably mean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, attr) {
        return attr + "&location=/xyz/123";
   });
});
</script>
```

That appends to the `href` of every link that has one (note I've changed the selector so we ignore anchors that don't have `href`s). It uses [the feature of the `attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) that accepts a function and calls it with each element, then uses the return value of the function to set the attribute (in your case, `href`) on the element.

Comment: I think you meant to add the `attr` argument to the inner function here?

Comment: @Gijs: Thank you, I did indeed. :) Fixed, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works for you.

**Edit**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('a').attr('href', function(i,val){
    return val+"&location=/xyz/123"
   })
});
</script>
```

Comment: The first attr() here will return a string. Assigning to that doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a[href]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "&location=/xyz/123");
    });
});
```

(adding `[href]` to the initial selector so you don't hit anchor elements)

Comment: Better to use the callback feature of `attr`, the above is quite inefficient, doing a lot of extra work and memory allocations. (Not my downvote, because it *would* work.)